# NetSuite / Suitescript - Focus on field on Page Load

Tags: cursor, workflow, netsuite, suitescript

Is there a way through workflow or suitescript to focus to a specific field when the page loads? I don't want a hack.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to access to the NetSuite UI using SuiteScript because it doesn't support direct access through the DOM. You need to use javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a client script to define the cursor location. In my example I use the field change but you should be able to apply the same logic to the pageinit.

```
function clientFieldChanged(type, name, linenum){
var nextElement = document.getElementsByName('inpt_custrecord_bathroom1_typeofbathroom');
nextElement[0].focus();
}
```

Comment: This does not work for me. Also, it looks like NetSuite does not support DOM so I would not want to try to script something they don't support. Thanks!